# Difference between count(*), max(count(*)), avg(count(*))

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to get the maximum and average of the api calls within a period of 10s from cloudwatch log insight. I have the query below. Is the query below correct? what are the differences between them?

`stats count(*) as count, max(count) as max, avg(count) as avg by bin(10s)`

Comment: Please run your query, and tell us what you determined.

Comment: @Marcin it seems that the value of count(*) is higher than max(count) and avg(count). So what is the difference between those 3?